# The TWTRComposerViewController not showing in Iphone-X Landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter

I'm using TWTRComposerViewController to share video on twitter my landscape app, it is working fine in all other device's except iPhone-X , when i try to share video in iPhone-X then composer not showing and the App freezes out.

I'm using the below written code:

```
if ([[Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore hasLoggedInUsers]) 
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

       TWTRComposerViewController *composer = [[TWTRComposerViewController  emptyComposer] initWithInitialText:@"Testing" image:nil videoURL:url];
       composer.delegate = self;

      [self presentViewController:composer animated:true completion:nil];
    });

 } 
 else 
 {

       [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {

                if (session) {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                   TWTRComposerViewController *composer = [[TWTRComposerViewController  emptyComposer] initWithInitialText:@"Testing" image:nil videoURL:url];
                   composer.delegate = self;

                  [self presentViewController:composer animated:true completion:nil];

                  });


                } else {

           NSLog(@"Error");
       }

  }
```

Comment: You seems to not be the only one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831671/twtrcomposerviewcontroller-not-appearing-in-iphone-x-landscape or from Twitter Dev forums https://twittercommunity.com/t/problem-in-using-twtrcomposerviewcontroller-iphonex-ios11-x/99827/11

Answer (score 0):

The glitch you are encountering with the `TWTRComposerViewController` is not your error, **nor** are you the only one dealing with this.

> This is a **bug** in Twitter's SDK.

Looking into Twitter's recent activity / attention to their SDK it seems their interface packages are lagging ever since the new **iPhone X** release. I would expect this to be resolved *sooner* than later.

---

I guess the *best temporary* solutions would be to either force your controller into portrait mode during this process, disable rotation for the appropriate controllers, or (though perhaps too *ugly*) present this VC in portrait, and rotate the view. Nonetheless, hopefully Twitter updates their SDK soon.

---

Report this as a bug to Twitter on their [developer forum](https://twittercommunity.com) to let them know about the issue, as they should eventually see the numerous posts of the same issue...